# Фильтрация строк таблицы по определенному имени в колонке

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework, mvvm

Вот класс сущности

```
public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Переменные, что после получения данных из БД будут возвращены свойствам

    private string название;
    private string жанр;
    private string автор;
    private string издательство;
    private int год_издания;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Название
    {
        get { return название; }
        set
        {
            название = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Название");
        }
    }

    public string Жанр
    {
        get { return жанр; }
        set
        {
            жанр = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Жанр");
        }
    }
    public string Автор
    {
        get { return автор; }
        set
        {
            автор = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Автор");
        }
    }
    public string Издательство
    {
        get { return издательство; }
        set
        {
            издательство = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Издательство");
        }

    }
    public int Год_Издания
    {
        get { return год_издания; }
        set
        {

            год_издания = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Год_Издания");
        }
    }
    //Объявление события, реагирующего на изменение данных
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
 public class InteractionDBViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DBContext db;
    IEnumerable<Book> books;

    public IEnumerable<Book> Books
    {
        get { return books; }
        set
        {

            books = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Books");
        }
    }
    // Загружаем данные из бд в локальный кэш
    public InteractionDBViewModel()
    {
        db = new DBContext();
        db.Books.Load();
        Books = db.Books.Local.ToBindingList();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

Форма для вывода данных

```
<Window x:Class="Books_DB_Application.DataWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Books_DB_Application"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="DataWindow" Height="450" Width="900">
<Grid>

    <DataGrid  x:Name="booksGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 AlternatingRowBackground="White" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Books }" >


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Название  }" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Жанр" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Жанр}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Автор" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Автор}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Издательство" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Издательство}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Год издания" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Год_Издания}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Главная форма

```
<Window x:Class="Books_DB_Application.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Books_DB_Application"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="200" >
        <Label Content="Выберите жанр книги" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" ></Label>
        <Button Content="Деловая литература" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click" ></Button>
        <Button Content="Искусство" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1"  ></Button>
        <Button Content="Книги для детей" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>
        <Button Content="Книги на иностранных языках" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_3"></Button>
        <Button Content="Красота Здоровье Спорт" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_4"></Button>
        <Button Content="Наука и образование" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_5" ></Button>
        <Button Content="Общество" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_6"></Button>
        <Button Content="Психология" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_7"></Button>
        <Button Content="Увлечения" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_8"></Button>
        <Button Content="Философия и религия" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_9"></Button>
        <Button Content="Художественная литература" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_10"></Button>

    </StackPanel>



</Grid>
```

[image: Отображение данных]

Нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки на форме вызывалась таблица с определенным жанром, есть мысль создать под каждый случай свою коллекцию книг, или всё переделать и использовать `System.Data.SqlClient;` передавая запросы в зависимости от кнопки, но может быть есть более удобный способ?

P.S.
Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый и сотню раз повторялся, просто мне всего несколько дней дали (не фриланс, просто помогаю)

Comment: Пользовать вводит значение => вы отправляете запрос в бд с фильтрацией по этому значению => получаете ответ из бд => показываете ответ в гриде пользователю

Comment: Да, спасибо, в общем так я и думал сделать, просто думал что есть решение по лучше, чуть позже скину свой вариант решения

Comment: это самый обычный типичнейший сценарий, тут нечего улучшать. Этот сценарий имеет смысл менять только если у вас какие то специфичные требования в вашей программе.

Comment: Да прост для удобства кнопочки под каждый жанр запилил, а так да, банально через запросы к бд. Вобщем завтра скину просто так, сейчас не за компом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сделал так

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Деловая литература'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Искусство'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Книги для детей'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Книги на иностранных языках'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Красота Здоровье Спорт'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Наука и образование'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Общество'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;

    }

    private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");


        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Психология'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Увлечения'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Философия и религия'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_10(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Жанр = 'Художественная литература'", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }

    private void Button_Click_11(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.db;");
        DB.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Books", DB);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        booksGrid.ItemsSource = reader;
    }
}
```

[image: Результат]
[image: Результат]

Возможно, код можно сократить, но с этим потом разберусь